# Bad temperature management on X1 Yoga

Tags: lenovo, cpu, overheating, fan, temperature

On my new ThinkPad X1 Yoga running Ubuntu 18.04 with thermald and TLP I noticed very annoying behaviour by the temperature management software:

1. The computer runs hot due to intensive load.
2. The CPUs throttle down to reduce heat production.
3. This spins up more CPUs to handle the same workload, which further increases the temperature.
4. The CPUs slow down even more, and the system becomes virtually unusable.

The first step is aggravated by the fan only turning on at fairly high temperatures.

My question is, which part of the software stack (e.g. firmware, OS, extra software like TLP and thermald) is responsible for which part of the temperature control measures (fan speed, CPU frequency, etc.)? One thing I would like to try is to lower the threshold for when to start the fan so ideally I could avoid get sucked into the above vicious cycle.